# I created a directive to apply the sticky header when achieve a certain distance from the top, but it isn't working as expected

Tags: css, angular, typescript

here's the template, when its get fixed, the width of the table changes and start ocupying the whole window:

[image]

```html
<div class="table-wrapper content">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" style="background-color: white; z-index: 1000;" appStickyHeader>
        <thead class="text-center">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 10%;" checkAll class="checkbox c-checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                        <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                    </label>
                </th>
                <th style="width:20%" (click)="filtroTableHeader('nomeFantasia')">
                    NOME
                    <span *ngIf="sortKey == 'nomeFantasia' && isAsc" class="fas fa-chevron-up">
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="sortKey == 'nomeFantasia' && !isAsc" class="fas fa-chevron-down">
                    </span>
                </th>
                <th style="width:10%" (click)="filtroTableHeader('tipoFornecedorId')">
                    TIPO
                    <span *ngIf="sortKey == 'tipoFornecedorId' && isAsc" class="fas fa-chevron-up"></span>
                    <span *ngIf="sortKey == 'tipoFornecedorId' && !isAsc" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></span>
                </th>
                <th style="width:10%">TELEFONE</th>
                <th style="width:10%">WHATSAPP</th>
                <th style="width:20%">E-MAIL</th>
                <th style="width:10%"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

but when it's get fixed, ocupy the full width like image below instead of stay with the same width, it seems as if the header is out of the box when it gets fixed, not taking into account the table width, below is the directive i've added:

```
    import {
  Directive,
  Renderer2,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  ElementRef
} from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[appStickyHeader]"
})
export class StickyHeaderDirective {
  @Input() public topOffset = 240;
  @Input() isContent = false;

  @HostListener("window:scroll", ["$event"])
  public windowScrolled($event) {
    console.log(this.isContent);
    if (this.isContent) {
      this.windowScrollEventContent();
    } else {
      this.windowScrollEvent($event);
    }
  }
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  windowScrollEventContent() {
    const isReachingTop = this.getTop() > this.topOffset;

    if (isReachingTop) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "margin-top", "100px");

    } else {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "margin-top", "initial");
    }
  }

  windowScrollEvent($event) {
    const isReachingTop = this.getTop() > this.topOffset;
    if (isReachingTop) {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "position", "fixed");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "top", "50px");

    } else {
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "position", "relative");
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.el.nativeElement, "top", "0");
    }
  }

  getTop() {
    return (
      window.pageYOffset ||
      document.documentElement.scrollTop ||
      document.body.scrollTop ||
      0
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: please reword your post so that it becomes clear what is the expected result, how the actual result is different and ask an actual question. Screenshots are not helpful enough, you should be more descriptive

Comment: the header of the table is changing the width when it's get fixed, simple as that

Comment: is this really angular-related? Could you attach the resulting HTML if not? Is there any CSS involved that you haven't shown? How do you make the header sticky? (please see [mcve]) I suspect that you apply `position: sticky` to a wrong element, but I can't be sure without an ability to reproduce the issue

Comment: i've added the directive I used to implement the sticky header.

Comment: ok, we're getting closer to what is needed. Could you create a stackblitz or something alike that reproduces the issue? I've threw your code to https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2tus2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts but it doesn't apply any stickiness